# How to make a proper star effect in Blender

Tags: animation

Is there anyone who can help me create a photorealistic star effect along the lines of this test video:

https://youtu.be/Zjw3fu4z7Wc

If you missed it, here's a screenshot (it's the blue one in front):

[image]

I'm aiming to get my star to be exactly like the front light blue one featured there in - a six pointer with thinner, sharper lines as opposed to the broader and more easily faded ones you usually get when you apply the glare effect.

Comment: Use the [Glare Node](https://www.blender.org/manual/compositing/types/filter/glare.html) in the compositor